# Get mean of bands in HDF file and save as geotiff

Tags: r, raster, hdf

I want to get the mean of bands of a HDF file and save as geotiff. To be specific MODIS MCD18A1 has 15 bands), I want "mean(band4:band11)"

MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_0000_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_0300_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_0600_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_0900_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_1200_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_1500_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_1800_DSR"
MCD18A1.A2001045.h24v06.006.20171801358.hdf:MODISRAD:GMT_2100_DSR

These are the bands in MODIS MCD18A1 short radiation product in HDF format, I want to take mean of these bands and then extract/save as "geotiff".

I can extract single band information but how to deal with multi band mean within HDF raster?

=============================================================
files corresponds to MCD18A1 HDF tiles.

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i])
  gdal_translate(sds[1],
    dst_dataset = paste0(basename(files[i]),".tif"),  
    of = "GTiff")  
}
```

==============================================================

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I download an example file with `luna` ([github](https://github.com/rspatial/luna)) and show how to process it with `terra` (CRAN)

```
library(luna)
e <- c(6.04,  6.23, 49.72, 49.91)
# for this you need to sign up with NASA for a username and pwd. It is free
f <- getModis("MCD18A1", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", e, path=".",
    download=TRUE, username="*****", password="*****")
f
#"./MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf"
```

You can skip the above, given that you already have a file `f`

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(f)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 240, 240, 21  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 4633.127, 4633.127  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1111951, 4447802, 5559753  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs 
#sources     : MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf:MODISRAD:DSR  (4 layers) 
#              MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf:MODISRAD:Direct  (4 layers) 
#              MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf:MODISRAD:Diffuse  (4 layers) 
#              ... and 9 more source(s)
#names       : MODIS~:DSR_1, MODIS~:DSR_2, MODIS~:DSR_3, MODIS~:DSR_4, MODIS~rect_1, MODIS~rect_2, ... 

names(r)
# [1] "MODISRAD:DSR_1"        "MODISRAD:DSR_2"        "MODISRAD:DSR_3"        "MODISRAD:DSR_4"        "MODISRAD:Direct_1"     "MODISRAD:Direct_2"    
# [7] "MODISRAD:Direct_3"     "MODISRAD:Direct_4"     "MODISRAD:Diffuse_1"    "MODISRAD:Diffuse_2"    "MODISRAD:Diffuse_3"    "MODISRAD:Diffuse_4"   
#[13] "MODISRAD:GMT_0000_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_0300_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_0600_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_0900_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_1200_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_1500_DSR"
#[19] "MODISRAD:GMT_1800_DSR" "MODISRAD:GMT_2100_DSR" "MODISRAD:DSR_Quality"
```

Pick the layers you want, e.g.

```
s <- r[[4:11]]
```

And compute the mean

```
x <- mean(s)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 240, 240, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 4633.127, 4633.127  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1111951, 4447802, 5559753  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :     mean 
#min value   : 10.92438 
#max value   : 70.07254
```

Save to geotiff

```
writeRaster(x, filename="test.tif")
```

Or in one step

```
 m <- app(r[[4:11]], mean, filename="test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

---

You can also read the file as a collection of subdatasets

```
 s <- sds(f)
 s
 #class       : SpatDataSet 
 #subdatasets : 12 
 #dimensions  : 240, 240 (nrow, ncol)
 #nlyr        : 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
 #resolution  : 4633.127, 4633.127  (x, y)
 #extent      : 0, 1111951, 4447802, 5559753  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 #coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs 
 #source(s)   : MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf 
 #names       : DSR, Direct, Diffuse, GMT_0000_DSR, GMT_0300_DSR, GMT_0600_DSR, GMT_0900_DSR, GMT_1200_DSR, GMT_1500_DSR, GMT_1800_DSR, GMT_2100_DSR, DSR_Quality
```

And extract subdatsets like this

```
s1 <- s[1]
s1
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 240, 240, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 4633.127, 4633.127  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1111951, 4447802, 5559753  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs 
#data source : MCD18A1.A2020001.h18v04.006.2020050045103.hdf:MODISRAD:DSR 
#names       : MCD_1, MCD_2, MCD_3, MCD_4
```